# syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end. when running rspec of feature file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rspec, capybara

```
require_relative 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.feature "testCreateVideo", :type => :feature do
  context 'create new video 'do
    scenario "Successfully creates a new video" do
      visit "https://SomeURL/orders"

      within('form') do

        fill_in "order[organisation][name]", :with => "SAMPLE BRAND NAME"
        fill_in "order[organisation][website]", :with => "SAMPLE WEBSITE"
        select "option", from:  "select box", :with => "Singapore"
        select "option", from:  "select box", :with => "Central"
        choose('order[project][name]', option: 'time_frame_next_week')
        choose('order[project][budget]', option: 'up-to-five')
        fill_in "#order_project_description", with: 'sample description'
        fill_in "order[project][videos_we_like_tmp]", :with => "My Widget"
        fill_in "order[contact][first_name]", :with => "John Christian"
        fill_in "order[contact][last_name]", :with => "Dela Pena"
        fill_in "order[contact][email]", :with => "christianmamac08@gmail.com"
        fill_in "order[contact][mobile]", :with => "65 8134 9249"
        check('accepts_terms')

      end

      click_button ('button')

      expect(page).to have_text("Thank you for creating your quote.")
    end

    scenario "should fail creating video" do
      visit "https://someURL/orders"

      within('form') do

        #fill_in "order[organisation][name]", :with => "SAMPLE BRAND NAME"
        fill_in "order[organisation][website]", :with => "SAMPLE WEBSITE"
        select "option", from:  "select box", :with => "Singapore"
        select "option", from:  "select box", :with => "Central"
        choose('order[project][name]', option: 'time_frame_next_week')
        choose('order[project][budget]', option: 'up-to-five')
        fill_in "#order_project_description", with: 'sample description'
        fill_in "order[project][videos_we_like_tmp]", :with => "My Widget"
        fill_in "order[contact][first_name]", :with => "John Christian"
        fill_in "order[contact][last_name]", :with => "Dela Pena"
        fill_in "order[contact][email]", :with => "christianmamac08@gmail.com"
        fill_in "order[contact][mobile]", :with => "65 8134 9249"
        check('accepts_terms')
      end
      click_button ('button')

      expect(page).to have_text("Brand Name is missing.")

    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed an `end` in the end, between those two `end`s lol

move from

```
    end
end
```

to

```
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I was laughing because of my sentence full of ends. is that so disturbing?

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to help the OP, I did not want to pretend to be professional

Comment: still the same. after I added an "end". is something wrong with my code? I'm new to rails.

Comment: @ChristianMamac: maybe you're missing another one. Or your code is cached by spring or something.

Comment: @ChristianMamac are you sure the error is in the same file? It seems this file just misses a single end